# Package hyperref error

Tags: hyperref, packages

With the following document class `\documentclass[a4paper,umbc4,colorBG,slideColor]{prosper}`

I am getting the following error when compiled

```
Package hyperref Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option `ps2pdf',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

Could someone help to sort it out?

Comment: Load `hyperref` _without_ any driver: `\usepackage{hyperref}` and, of course, run the document with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: loaded hyperref but still the problem persists.

Comment: You cannot run pdflatex with prosper

Comment: To elaborate on Herbet's comment,  for `prosper` you need to run the command `latex`, not `pdflatex`, on your file.  The `prosper` class is rather old, `beamer` is a modern alternative.